# JS thinks function is undefined, even though it clearly exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

*This question is related to [Function is undefined, Bookshelf.js model function is not being recognized as a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706043/function-is-undefined-bookshelf-js-model-function-is-not-being-recognized-as-a/32706099?noredirect=1#32706099)*

I am using [**`Bookshelf.js`**](http://bookshelfjs.org/) to handle user register/login API-endpoints, built with NodeJS and ExpressJS. However, when POSTing to the login route, Bookshelf throws the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at \routes\index.js:217:36
    at Strategy.strategy.success (\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:194:18)
    at verified (\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)
    at null.<anonymous> (\config\passport.js:17:20)

...
```

The following is routes/index.js

```
var User = require('./models/User');
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    if(user){
      return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The following is models/Users.js

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf');

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  validPassword: function(password, encryptedPass) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, encryptedPass, function (err, match) {
        if(err) return reject(err);
        resolve(match);
      });
    });
  },
  generateJWT: function() {
    // set expiration to 60 days
    var today = new Date();
    var exp = new Date(today);
    exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

    return jwt.sign({
      _id: this._id,
      email: this.email,
      exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
    }, 'SECRET');
  }
}, {
  createPassword: function (password) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(hash);
        });
      });
    });
  }
});

module.exports = User;
```

and here is config/passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/Users');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(email, password, done) {
    new User({email: email}).fetch().then(function(data) {
      var user = data;
      var curr_user = this;
      if(user === null) {
         return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
      } else {
         user = data.toJSON();
         if (!curr_user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
         } else {
            return done(null, user);
         }
      }
    });
  }
));
```

Is this an async/promise issue? Or have I gone wrong somewhere else?

Comment: So the issue is that `generateJWT` does not exist? Or what? Is the value of `user` what you expect?

Comment: @tyler Last I checked, JSFiddle et al don't do Node.js

Comment: JS doesn't "think". If it says it doesn't exist in the calling context, it doesn't exist in the calling context. Did you remember to take scoping into account? Because it's a good bet those callbacks don't preserver call context. What's on `\routes\index.js:217:36`?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what is
`at \routes\index.js:217:36`, it's very difficult to begin to attempt to answer this question.

Edit: However, `at Strategy.strategy.success` does suggest that it is an issue with a Promise not being returned. In other words, you are probably doing something like

```
ThinkingYouAreReturningAPromiseInThisFunction
  .success(function(result) {
    // stuff
  });
```

but are not in fact returning a Promise object in `ThinkingYouAreReturningAPromiseInThisFunction()`. In other words,  `success()` is not a function. Generally, a Promise object would have a method like `success()`. But if no such object is being returned, then `undefined is not a function`. I would begin troubleshooting there.